# String.Format in foreach loop for printing in the same line

Tags: c#, json, string, visual-studio, format

I have a function with which I read a Json and deserialize it. The JSON is nested and what I want is to print some nested values in the same line.

My JSON is that:

```
{
"number": 123,
"person": [{
    "phone": 864556,
    "name": "John D",
    "address": "N.Y",
    "email": "test@test.com"
},
{
    "phone": 19845,
    "name": "Mary S",
    "address": "N.Y",
    "email": "testmary@test.com"
},
{
    "phone": 34936,
    "name": "Alex N",
    "address": "Santiago",
    "email": "alex@test.com"
},
{
    "phone": 197478,
    "name": "Bill McK",
    "address": "London",
    "email": "test@example.com"
    }]
 }
```

and I have this

```
foreach (var num in JMain.person)
{
      debugOutput(String.Format("<{0};>", num.phone));
}

private void debugOutput(string strDebugText)
    {
        try
        {
            outPut += strDebugText + Environment.NewLine;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(strDebugText + Environment.NewLine);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

where debugOutput is the function in which I read the JSON and print it. What I want is to print all the phones in one line. With for loop and String.Format I can print them one down the other. Maybe isn't right to use String.Format and there is another way?

Thank you

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by print. You need to add your debugOutput function. At a guess you need to use Console.Write as opposed to Console.WriteLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the output in one string, you could do it like this. Depending on what's in your debugOutput function, there might be easier ways though.

```
string outputstring = "";
foreach (var num in JMain.person)
        {
            outputstring += String.Format("<{0};>", num.phone);
        }
debugOutput(outputstring);
```

Comment: Prefer using StringBuilder for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a single `string` from multiple parts, use `string.Join`:

```
var phones = string.Join("", JMain.person.Select(num => string.Format("<{0};>", num.phone));
```

First argument of `Join` is separator. Use `""` if you do not want any separation between individual formatted strings.

The above replaces your `foreach` loop. Print `phones` on a single line with

```
debugOutput(phones);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are valid, but for your code, the issue is your use of NewLine:

```
 private void debugOutput(string strDebugText)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(strDebugText);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```